# Java crash after Kernel Upgr. in Redhat 6.7

Tags: java, kernel, redhat

After an Kernel upgrade in our RedHat environment with release 6.7, we get the following error.

> ## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> ## SIGBUS (0x7) at pc=0x00007f964ce0febc, pid=2568, tid=140283767625472
>
> #
>
> ## JRE version:  (8.0_91-b14) (build )
>
> ## Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.91-b14 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>
> ## Problematic frame:
>
> ## j  java.lang.Object.()V+0
>
> #
>
> ## Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
>
> #
>
> ## If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>
> ## http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this actually a programming question.  You also don't mention the exact kernel RPM version and the JVM you run, making diagnosis rather difficult.

But I assume this is a kernel regression introduced by the fixed for this vulnerability:

- https://access.redhat.com/security/vulnerabilities/stackguard

For Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.7 (EUS), you need to upgrade to `kernel-2.6.32-573.43.3.el6` to address this regression:

- https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2017-1718.html